# Is there a way to see all the closed or deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, search, deleted-questions, closed-questions, 10k-tools

Is there a way to see all the closed or deleted questions both in the main and the meta?
I searched the meta to see if the same(or similar) question was asked before, but I couldn't find it.
If the answer is well-known, my apology is in order.

Comment: See also our help center: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching regarding the closed questions, as well as other search tips.

Answer (score 14):

No.

There are lists (on the meta and the main, separately) which you can access if you have 10k points or more, through `review` and then clicking `tools` and choosing the appropriate tab. These lists, however, do not include *everything*, they are limited in both time range and length.

The lists go only as far as 30 days the most. On the main site, however, due to high traffic of deletions (mostly by the Community clean up procedure) the list will often only include things from the past two-three days or so.

Beyond that you have to rely on your bookmarks, lists that you have saved elsewhere, favorites (you can view deleted favorites), and your browsing history.

As for closed questions, you can search for `is:q closed:yes` in the search box, and find all the closed questions. Currently there are over 10,000 of them. So additional parameters may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: Sure there's a way. Step 1: be elected ♦-moderator on math.SE. Step 2: use the `deleted:yes` search parameter, which you gained access to after completing Step 1. Easy peasy! ;-) (An alternative to Step 1 is Step 1': be hired by Stack Exchange as a Community Manager or Developer.)

Comment: @Arthur: Alternative alternative, get hired by the company which maintains the servers of SE/hack your way through everything/Get a job in the NSA. :-)

Comment: @ above: Alternative^3, sure there is another way, you can be a programmer hacker.

Comment: @Idear: I already listed that alternative.